# On the EuroMillions lottery

Tags: combinations, lotteries

To play the [EuroMillions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EuroMillions) lottery, one selects five *main* numbers from $1$ to $50$ and two *Lucky Stars* numbered from $1$ to $11$.

[image]

I would like to know what the number of possibilities is given the following constraints:

- **Constraint #1:** one can not pick adjacent numbers (e.g., $1$ and $2$, or $7$ and $8$). This constraint applies both to main numbers and Lucky Star numbers.
- **Constraint #2:** one can pick at most **two** *main* numbers from each "decimal house" ($1$ to $10$, $11$ to $20$,...).

Comment: Your question needs at least the information of how many "decimal houses" there are, and also a better description of the proviso "occasionally picking two numbers on the same house." Also is only one case allowed of a house with two numbers chosen from it?

Comment: it's not so trivial because for example 19 and 20 ... nice question

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Since you are the user who created that tag, I thought it might be reasonable to point out that the tag is now being discussed on meta: [Why does the “lotteries” tag exist?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25679)

Answer (score 0):

What is the number of possibilities of number sets knowing that one can only pick a number for each decimal house ?

If we have to choose one number from 1 to 10,
one number from 11 to 20,
one number from 21 to 30,
one number from 31 to 40,
one number from 41 to 50:

NUMBER OF POSSIBILITIES = 10 * 10 * 10 *10 *10 = 10^5

Comment: it is *at most two main numbers* not *exactly one*